# jetty deploy war file

Tags: tomcat, jetty, war

I create a grails app,and it runs fine in IDEA,then I package it as a war file named `api.war` by gradle.After jetty(version is 9.3.7) deploy it,I access it in chrome.[Something wrong like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZWSD.png).The app cannot acess the data while I can access the data if I enter the url "http://localhost:8080/api/json/xxx.json" in browser directly.

Then I rename it as `root.war` so that I can access it through root path.The app works!It can access data perfectly.

If I have two apps,both of them like `api.war`.As you see,the root path can not be half,what should I do?BTW,I can't find any folders in webapps after deploying.Is this the difference between tomcat and jetty?

Comment: Maybe you have relative paths in your app. If you deploy it named ROOT.war, it will be placed at the root context of your server (having no app name in the url).

Comment: Yeah ,I understand what you say.  I Just wonder what should I do if I MUST deploy two apps ?Both of them have relative paths.

Comment: Let me understand. Do you have a single war file and you want to deploy them in different contexts?

Comment: @josivan yes,suppose I duplicate it,so I have app1.war and app2.war,I want them both work fine.I have to sleep now ,good night :D

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to duplicate your war files. Take a look in the steps bellow, these can help you:

1. copy your file to a folder in your file system. For example under `/opt/war`
2. create two xml files under your webapps folder.
3. define each xml as describe bellow;

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" 
    "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">
<Configure id="app1" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="war">/opt/war/app.war</Set>
    <Set name="contextPath">/app1</Set>
</Configure>
```

For each one application you need to define the id and the `contextPath`.

I hope that the answer help you

Comment: I have tried before I ask.When I set the contextPath as `/api`,the app still try to acess the data through " http://localhost:8080/json/xxx.json". In fact ,the location of data is " http://localhost:8080/api/json/xxx.json". I just wonder about why the app still try to access data through the wrong url after I set contextPath as `/api`.Everything would works fine only if I set contextPath as `/`.

Comment: How did you declare the api context/path in application?

Comment: In file `application.yml`? I didn't set it.

Comment: URL="/json/xxx.json",then function of swagger UI will process it.  This is JavaScript.

Comment: Try to remove the initial slash

Comment: I don't have experience with swagger. But I believe that the mapping of URL must be relative instead of absolute. Maybe you need to rewrite your question with more details and someone else can help you.